# Stop checking other conditions if first condition is met in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table which looks as follows:

```
ID  ContactId  EffectiveToDate  EffectiveFromDate  Maximum_EffectiveToDate ID_count
1    68        Null             10-2-2005           11-3-2006                2
2    68        11-3-2006        13-1-2006           11-3-2006                2
3    78        Null             01-01-2000          Null                     1
4    80        10-10-2004       19-09-2003          10-10-2004               1
5    82        15-08-2002       19-06-2001          15-08-2002               3
6    82        10-06-2001       01-01-2000          15-08-2002               3
7    82        Null             20-10-2004          15-08-2002               3
8    85        10-06-2005       10-05-2004          10-06-2005               2
9    85        11-07-2004       10-04-2003          10-06-2005               2
```

ID-count is the count of `ContactId` column. I want to select the rows in a way that `ContactId` appears once (no repetition) and the condition is:

1. pick data where ContactId that appears one time (i.e. ID_count =1)
2. If ContactId appears more than one time (i.e. ID_count >1) then pick only rows where EffectiveToDate is Null
3. If ContactId appears more than one time (i.e. ID_count > 1) and EffectiveToDate is not null then pick the row where `EffectiveToDate` value is equal to Maximum_EffectiveToDate

I wrote the following SQL code to satisfy above-mentioned conditions:

```
Select * from table
where (ID_count = 1 or (ID_count > 1 AND EffectiveToDate is Null) or
       (ID_count > 1 AND EffectiveToDate is not Null AND EffectiveToDate = Maximum_EffectiveToDate))
```

The problem with the above code is that it returns rows where ContactId 82 and 68 two times. One row with `EffectiveToDate` with Null and one row when `EffectiveToDate` is equal to `Maximum_EffectiveToDate`. Is there any way in SQL where we stop the remaining conditions to check if the first condition is true?

Comment: A `WHERE` can't cause a row to be returned twice. If you are getting the row twice, this is because 2 rows exist in the table that meet the requirements of `WHERE`.

Comment: Rules 2 and 3 contradict each other. There is no guarantee that Rule 3 will **not** include multiple rows for a given ContactID (though same applies to the other rules). If your goal is to include one row per ContactID, you should write your requirements with the logic explicitly defined using that as a basis. With that in mind, this sounds like you need a typical "first in group" query - which is what Stu posted.

Comment: What is the expected results from the above sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number` to assign a rank for each row and return the first qualifying row:

```
select ID, ContactId, EffectiveToDate, EffectiveFromDate, Maximum_EffectiveToDate, ID_count
from (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() over(
      partition by ContactId
      order by ID_count, EffectiveToDate, Iif(EffectiveToDate = Maximum_EffectiveToDate, 0, 1)
    ) rn
  from t
)t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using **UNION** to achieve desired result.

```
select * from table where ContactId in (
    select ContactId from table group by ContactId having count(1) = 1)
union
select * from table where ContactId in (
    select ContactId from table group by ContactId having count(1) > 1)
and isnull(EffectiveToDate, '') = ''
union
select * from (
    select row_number() over (partition by ContactId order by EffectiveToDate desc) rn,
        * from table where isnull(EffectiveToDate, '') != '')
where rn = 1 and ContactId not in (select ContactId from table group by ContactId having count(1) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amend the third condition to check for the EXISTence of a null record

```
select *
from t
where id_count = 1 or
      (id_count > 1 and effectivetodate is null) or
      (not exists(select 1 from t t1 where t1.contactid = t.contactid and t1.effectivetodate is null) and effectiveToDate = Maximum_EffectiveToDate)
;
```